# Bootstrap modal. In body not present modal-open class

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

My project is using bootstrap-modal. I need to show several windows one by one.
I'm using such function to create parent window:

```
function createModalWindow(windowid,parentid,modelname,elementid,add_data, default_template){
    var url = '/invoice_settings/get_template/' + modelname ;
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
            success: function(data){
                var template = default_template;
                var body_template = data[0]['fields']['template'];

                template = template.replace('\{\{body_template\}\}', body_template);

                //skipped

                $(('#' + windowid)).detach();
                $("body").append(template);
                $(('#' + windowid)).modal('show');
                        //skipped

                $('#' + windowid).data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();
            },
            error: function () {
                        //skipped
            }
        });
}
```

In body-tag present class 'modal-open' and modal window work fine (for example, scroll work in modal and not work under it)

```
<body class="modal-open" style="">
```

From this window i try to create child window:

```
function selectElementUsingChildWindow(row_id, parentid, windowid, modelname, fieldname, default_template) {
    var url = '/invoice_settings/get_select_element_from_table/json/' + modelname + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            var template = default_template;
            template = template.replace('\{\{body_template\}\}', clearTblWithHeader);

            //skipped

            $(('#' + windowid)).detach();
            $('body').append(template);

            if(parentid.localeCompare("")!=0){
                $(('#' + parentid)).modal('hide'); //parentid is parent window ID. windowid - is current(child) window ID
            }
            $(('#' + windowid)).modal('show');

            $('#' + windowid).attr('data-row-id', row_id); // adding some info
            gen_body_tamplate_for_select_element_from_tbl(data, windowid, modelname); // add some data to table in child window (I'm using datatables)
            $('#' + windowid).data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();

        },
        error: function (data) {
           //skipped
        }
    });
}
```

And now i receive a problem. My modal window viewed fine, but body-tag hasn't 'modal-open' class. Of course my modal window not scroll. Page under it scroll fine :).

```
<body class style >
```

My child window has height more then browser window and the window is not wet on the screen. $('#' + windowid).data('bs.modal').handleUpdate() - is not working.
I tried to set 'modal-open' class manualy. 
After gen_body_tamplate_for_select_element_from_tbl() I called checkOnModalOpen() function:

```
function selectElementUsingChildWindow(row_id, parentid, windowid, modelname, fieldname, default_template) {
    var url = '/invoice_settings/get_select_element_from_table/json/' + modelname + '/';
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {

            //skipped
            gen_body_tamplate_for_select_element_from_tbl(data, windowid, modelname); // add some data to table in child window (I'm using datatables)
            checkOnModalOpen(windowid);
            $('#' + windowid).data('bs.modal').handleUpdate();

        },
        error: function (data) {
           //skipped
        }
    });
}

function checkOnModalOpen(windowid) {
    console.log('checkOnModalOpen(windowid) ' + $('body').hasClass('modal-open'));
    if ($('body').hasClass('modal-open')==false){
        $('body').addClass('modal-open');
    }
}
```

But everytime $('body').hasClass('modal-open') is returning True.

How can I fix this problem? 
Why is the class 'modal-open' everytime removed from body-tag and I can not add class manualy?

Comment: Can you just create a plnkr or fiddle ? and update your question?

Comment: I'll try to do it. But I don't know whether the site will display the changes in the body-tag

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve just put in plnkr or jsfiddle. and share the link.